# Visual Studio. Не работает консруктор

Tags: c#, visual-studio

столкнулся со следующей проблемой, когда я хочу открыть проект или создать новый отображается следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До этого ничего такого не было, все работало. Думал переустановить, но не получается, при удалении возникает остановка программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту проблему ?

Comment: у вас конструктор класса на работает или проект не создается?

Comment: Проект создается, а вот конструктор нет.